# Redirect link in the jsf at the beginning of the page

Tags: java, jsf

I am using jsf. When I used the h:commandButton in the jspx page. I could call the function of the managed bean to return a string then post to other page. I would like to ask could I call the managed bean to do the action when I first entered the page. I would like to fire the action in the managed bean without clicking any button. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using PreRenderView event. Lets say you have a managedBean like this

```
import javax.faces.application.ConfigurableNavigationHandler;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;

@ManagedBean(name="listener")
@SessionScoped
public class ListenerBean{

  public void handleEvent(ComponentSystemEvent event){
    // Handle event, do your thing, and redirect again if you need
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ConfigurableNavigationHandler nav = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    nav.performNavigation("my-navigation-rule");
  } 
}
```

And on your xhtml (sorry I do not know jspx version of it, I hope you can convert it to your templating style).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <f:event listener="#{listener.handleEvent}" type="preRenderView" />

    <h:body>
.... 
    </h:body>

</html>
```